# Star printing in C the hard way

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, geometry

I've started exercising some C and found this nice exercise where I have to print a triangle via input.
for the input 6 it will print

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Now, looking at it I thought, well, that's not such a hard task. So I decided to try and write it using recursion, no loops and only 2 variables.
the function should looks like this:

```
void PrintTriangle(int iMainNumber, int iCurrNumber)
{
   //Logic goes here
}
```

A few hours later I realized this is a lot harder than I thought, since I need to pass enough information for the function to be able to "remember" how much triangles it should print.

So now I decided to ask you if that is even possible.

(remember, no loops, no other functions, only recursion).

**EDIT:**
This isn't homework, this is out of sheer curiosity. However I probably can't validate for you.
I've managed to get halfway through with this

```
void PrintTriangle(int iMainNumber, int iCurrNumber)
{
    if (iMainNumber == 0)
    {
        printf("\r\n");
    }
    else if (iMainNumber == iCurrNumber)
    {
        printf("\r\n");
        PrintTriangle(iMainNumber - 1, 0);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s", MYCHAR);
        PrintTriangle(iMainNumber, iCurrNumber + 1);
    }
}
```

I got stuck trying to create the opposite function, I believe that if I could do it, I would be able to use the fact that iMainNumber and iCurrNumber are positive or negative to navigate through the functions flow.

In other words, when the parameters are negative I would print a descending star in the length of the input minus one, and when the parameters are positive I would print the ascending star in the length of the input.

I've thought about Using a flag, but not instead of 2 integers.

Maybe if I'd add another flag and have 2 integers and a flag then I could solve it, but as I said, I tried to limit myself to 2 integers.

What I'm starting to think is that there is no way to pass the information required to print an ascending star in this method without using more than 2 integers and recursion.

But I'm still not so sure about that, hence the question.

Comment: I'd probably use one of them as a flag...

Comment: This looks like homework...  Otherwise, you don't really meet the SO guidelines for a question.  Show us what you tried and what errors or problems you had.

Comment: The whole point of homework is to learn something.

Comment: what do you mean with it needs to remember how much it should print? iMainNumber starts with 1, then in the next recursive call it's 2, until it's equal to iCurrNumber.

Comment: Hint: you can count *up* until you reach twice the number of stars you want to print...

Comment: Added what I got till now.
Counting up until I reach twice the number of stars I want to print will be like using a weaker version of an int and another parameter.
In a way...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came up with:

```
void PrintTriangle(int size, int indent)
{
    switch(size) {
    case 0:
        if (indent > 1) PrintTriangle(size, indent-1);
        putchar('*');
        break;
    case 1:
        PrintTriangle(size-1, indent+1);
        putchar('\n');
        break;
    default:
        PrintTriangle(1, indent);
        PrintTriangle(size-1, indent+1);
        PrintTriangle(1, indent);
        break; }
}

int main()
{
    PrintTriangle(6, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

as a quick first attempt.  Seems to do the job.

`size` is the size of the triangle to print, and `indent` is the number of extra stars to print before each row of the triangle.  `size==0` means just print `indent` stars and no newline (used to print the indent before the triangle)

If you want something a bit more compact, you could rewrite this as:

```
void PrintTriangle(int size, int indent)
{
    if (size <= 0) {
        if (indent > 1) PrintTriangle(size, indent-1);
        putchar('*');
    } else {
        if (size > 1) PrintTriangle(1, indent);
        PrintTriangle(size-1, indent+1);
        if (size > 1) PrintTriangle(1, indent);
        else putchar('\n'); }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Anything done with loops can be done with recursion with the same number of variables. You just have to tease out what is the state, and pass that updated state in a recursive call, instead of looping.

So let's do it iterativey, first. The input is `size`, the size of the triangle. Let's have two state variables, `lineNumber` from 1 to `size*2-1` and `columnNumber` from 1 to `size`. Note that:

```
columnsForLine = lineNumber <= size ? lineNumber : size*2 - lineNumber
```

The iterative version would be like this:

```
int lineNumber = 1;
int columnNumber = 1;
int size = 6;
while (lineNumber <= size*2-1) {        
    printf("*");
    int columnsForLine = lineNumber <= size ? lineNumber : size*2 - lineNumber;
    if (columnNumber == columnsForLine) {
        printf("\n");
        columnNumber = 1;
        lineNumber += 1; 
    }
    else {
        columnNumber += 1;
    }
}
```

That [does indeed work](http://codepad.org/zCOmtWbG). Now how to do it recursively? Just tease out where state is being updated and do that as a recursive call:

```
void recstars(int size, int lineNumber, int columnNumber) {
    if (!(lineNumber <= size*2 - 1)) {
        return;
    }
    printf("*");
    int columnsForLine = lineNumber <= size ? lineNumber : size*2 - lineNumber;
    if (columnNumber == columnsForLine) {
        printf("\n");
        recstars(size, lineNumber + 1, 1);
    }
    else {
        recstars(size, lineNumber, columnNumber + 1);
    }
}
recstars(6, 1, 1);
```

And [voila](http://codepad.org/HYN0GjLE). Works for any size, e.g. [13](http://codepad.org/eSUKFzRV).

Note that the code is basically the same, it's just a matter of doing the control flow differently. Also note that this is tail-recursive, meaning a smart compiler would be able to execute the recursive calls without growing the stack for each call.

---

Hmm if you only want to use 2 variables though, including the input, will be a bit trickier... you can always cheat and stuff all 3 integers into one integer, then unpack it & re-pack it each time. e.g.

```
void recstars(int state) {
    int size = state / 10000;
    int lineNumber = (state - size*10000) / 100;
    int columnNumber = state - size*10000 - lineNumber*100;
    if (!(lineNumber <= size*2 - 1)) {
        return;
    }
    printf("*");
    int columnsForLine = lineNumber <= size ? lineNumber : size*2 - lineNumber;
    if (columnNumber == columnsForLine) {
        printf("\n");
        recstars(size*10000 + (lineNumber+1)*100 + 1);
    }
    else {
        recstars(size*10000 + lineNumber*100 + (columnNumber+1));
    }
}
recstars(6*10000 + 1*100 + 1);
```

[Seems to work](http://codepad.org/F8ZHKfUR). Is that legit, you think?

Otherwise, the tricky part isn't the recursion, it's just getting the job done with only 2 ints for state. Can you do it iteratively with only 2 integers?

Comment: Well, I didn't want to cheat by packing my number.

Answer (score 1):

Using 2 parameters as OP suggested

```
void PrintTriangle(int iMainNumber, int iCurrNumber) {
  if (iMainNumber < 0) { // Row (use negative iMainNumber)
    printf("%c", '*');
    PrintTriangle(iMainNumber + 1, 0);
    if (iMainNumber == -1)
      printf("\n");
  } else if (iMainNumber > 0) { 
    if (iCurrNumber < iMainNumber) { // Preceding short lines
      if (iCurrNumber > 1)
        PrintTriangle(iMainNumber, iCurrNumber - 1);
      PrintTriangle(-iCurrNumber, 0);
    } else if (iCurrNumber == iMainNumber) { 
      PrintTriangle(iMainNumber, iCurrNumber - 1);  // left
      PrintTriangle(iMainNumber, iCurrNumber + 1);  // Right
    } else {                         // Subsequent short lines
      if ((iCurrNumber - iMainNumber) < iMainNumber)
        PrintTriangle(iMainNumber, iCurrNumber + 1);
      PrintTriangle(-(iCurrNumber - iMainNumber), 0);
    }
  }
}

int main() {
  PrintTriangle(3,3);
  PrintTriangle(6,6);
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: @GLaDOS Suspected better solution existed.  Suggest leaving a comment with the "former checked solution" provider with a parting thought.

Answer (score 0):

From what I have read, most suggestions have already pointed out to pass in any state you need.

However, you really don't need that many branching statements. Most of what you need, you can derive arithmetically. You can calculate the total number of recursions and derive the number of stars from the current recursion count. Also, by separating the portion of the initial invocation from the recursion, you can make usage much simpler.

Just saw that you do not want more than two integers. Consider the below and see if you really want to maintain that preference. If so, you can put the calculation of the total in the recursive portion. I think it would be less readable.

```
void _print_stars(int height, int total, int current)
{
    int stars = current <= height ? current : 2 * height - current;

    for (int i = 0; i < stars; i++) { printf("*"); }
    printf("\n");

    if (current != total)
    {
        _print_stars(height, total, current + 1);
    }
}

void print_stars(int height)
{
    int total_recursions = 2 * height - 1;
    _print_stars(height, total_recursions, 1);
}
```

Comment: No loops either! :( I guess that means I should only print one star per recursion and the for loop is illegal.  Too bad - it looked so much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Pure recursion, no loops, calling program 'main()' passes only one parameter:

```
void PrintTheClms(int width, int stars) {
    printf("*");
    if stars < width then {
      PrintTheClms(width, stars+1);
    }
}

void PrintStars(int  width) {
    PrintTheClms(width, 1);
    printf("\n");
}

void PrintTheRows(int size, int indent) {
    PrintStars(indent);
    if indent < size then {
      PrintTheRows(size, indent+1);
      PrintStars(indent);
    }
}

void PrintTriangle(int size) {
    if size > 0 then {
      PrintTheRows(size, 1);
    }
}

int main() {
    PrintTriangle(6);
    PrintTriangle(11);
    // etc.
    return 0;
}
```

Very simple -- no else clauses, no case constructs, no direction flag. Lots of procs and lots of calls, though.